# How to specify a complex datatype input in a SOAP Request in SoapUI tool

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xml-serialization, soapui

I need some help using the SoapUI tool.

I'm testing webServices APIs using this tool.

There is an API called **"getUsageReport()"** which takes 2 input parameters

- **`<datasources>`** of type  **`<akaaurdt:ArrayOfString>`**
- **`<start date>`**  of type  **`<xsd:string>`**

**`<akaaurdt:ArrayOfString>`** is defined as below.

```
<complexType name="ArrayOfString">
  <complexContent>
  <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
  <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]" /> 
  </restriction>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

the request xml in soap UI is as below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bil="https://control.akamai.com/BillingReports.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bil:getUsageReport soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <datasources xsi:type="bil:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
         <startDate xsi:type="xsd:string">?</startDate>
      </bil:getUsageReport>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

when I click on RUN by giving a date in the request, this is the response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode>
         <faultstring>akaaurdt:ApplicationError:ApplicationError:(?? No Data for Given Start Date.  Please resubmit with a more recent date)</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns1:exceptionName xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">com.akamai.aws.util.AWSFault</ns1:exceptionName>
            <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">qa-portal-ws01.qaextranet.akamai.com</ns2:hostname>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How do I specify the `<datasources>` parameter in this request xml to get the desired response?

Please help me with this

-Kiran

Answer (score 2):

1. Run getReports (or getReportingGroups) of the BillingReports. Lets say it returns a contractCode called 55555.
2. Run method getUsageReport and it should look like the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bil="https://control.akamai.com/BillingReports.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bil:getUsageReport soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <datasources xsi:type="bil:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
        <datasource xsi:type="xsd:string">55555</datasource>
    </datasources>
         <startDate xsi:type="xsd:string">20120620</startDate>
      </bil:getUsageReport>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should specify the date

```
<startDate xsi:type="xsd:string">?</startDate>
```

it's required in the request, the date format i don't know how it is defined, because it's string type, and not the date type.

Try with `yyyy/MM/dd`, is the date format type.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I have specified the date actually. But the documentation says there are 2 input parameters for this API in the order `<datasources> <startDate>`. But I am not able to give the other input i.e `<datasources>`. I need help on that

Comment: something like that: `<item xsi:type="bil:ArrayOfString">
<item xsi:type="xsd:string">jdbc/resourceName</item><item xsi:type="xsd:string">jdbc/resourceName</item></item>`

Comment: @Cristian.. which of the following is correct .. pls help me     <bil:getUsageReport soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
             <datasources xsi:type="bil:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
       <datasources xsi:type="bil:ArrayOfString"> 
             <datasources xsi:type="xsd:string">1-FO0A7</datasources>
             <startDate xsi:type="xsd:string">20110110</startDate>
    </bil:getUsageReport>

Comment: @Cristian.. which of the following is correct .. pls help me                                        `<bil:getUsageReport soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <datasources xsi:type="bil:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>                                                        <datasources xsi:type="bil:ArrayOfString"> 
    <datasources xsi:type="xsd:string">1-FO0A7</datasources>
    <startDate xsi:type="xsd:string">20110110</startDate>
    </bil:getUsageReport>`

Comment: or this `<bil:getUsageReport soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <!--<datasources xsi:type="bil:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>-->
  <datasources xsi:type="bil:ArrayOfString"> 
         <datasources xsi:type="xsd:string">1-FO0A7</datasources>
         <!--<datasources xsi:type="xsd:string">jdbc/resourceName</datasources>-->
         </datasources>
         <startDate xsi:type="xsd:string">20101201</startDate>`

Comment: the last request, your <starDate></starDate> is located out from the <dataSource></dataSource> in the schema

Comment: i hv tried this  `<datasources soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
  <datasources xsi:type="xsd:string">3-7ZOALT</datasources>
 </datasources>
    <startDate xsi:type="xsd:string">20110901</startDate>`

Comment: response is this  `<faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
         <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">qa-portal-ws01.qaextranet.akamai.com</ns1:hostname>
         </detail>
`

Comment: **i tried this** `<bil:getUsageReport soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <datasources xsi:type="bil:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
   <datasources xsi:type="xsd:string">3-7ZOALT</datasources>
  </datasources>
        <startDate xsi:type="xsd:string">20110901</startDate>  
</bil:getUsageReport>`

Comment: **this is the response**  `<faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode>
         <faultstring>akaaurdt:InvalidDataSource:The data source is invalid:(3-7ZOALT)</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns1:exceptionName xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">com.akamai.aws.util.AWSFault</ns1:exceptionName>
            <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">qa-portal-ws01.qaextranet.akamai.com</ns2:hostname>
         </detail>
`

Answer (score 0):

You never want to submit a request with ? placeholders.  Edit the request so there's actual data.

Comment: @Chrish: hi Chris.. nope.. i'm specifying the date but facing issues with the other datatype

Comment: in my soap request i need to replace this line         `<datasources xsi:type="bil:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>`                                      with an actual array of string.                                         Can you please help me with this